# Storing Parameters in Session in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I have a J2ME Application.Now i have to store parameters of a login form in session so that it can be used in another form.So,how to implement Sessions in J2me.I am using Http POST/GET for connecting WebServices.

Answer (score 0):

In Java ME there is no concept of Session Variables. So as per rule of the Object Oriented, the method which is not in-build, you need to create your **own method**.

Let me guide you in it, you can achieve it in two following ways ( as per my experience, there may be more ways to implement too )

- Create Getter/Setter methods
- Create Public Static methods

Comment: Lucifer:Thanx.Do you know about HttpConnection Requests?

Comment: @user1520655, yes, little bit

Comment: Ok.Can Getter/Setter be used (as suggested by you) for storing Login parameters,i think at this point Session is needed.That's y i was asking you for HttpRequests.

Comment: Can you explain me how can we do this?I am getting your point but it will be very helpful to me if you explain this with an example.

Comment: sure, but i want you to first try your self, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getter%20setter%20method%20in%20java)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17217/discussion-between-user1520655-and-lucifer)

Comment: @user1520655, at present my net speed is very low, so i can not login to chat room, sorry for it.

Comment: It's ok.Actually i have to do this for different Forms of my Application.So was a lil bit confused regarding Getter/Setter because everybody was suggesting Session in this matter.Will try by Getter/Setter and will let you know.I will try to solve this problem via this first.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use HttpConnection request properties. There is a very good article available at
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2002/jw-0426-wireless.html

The author created an RMSCookieConnector and an HttpRMSCookieConnection to store the cookies info in RMS.

Comment: Telmo: Thanks.But will do a favour?Actually i am new to session topic,so can you please give me example regarding this.This blog is informative but i need another example.Simple example will be perfect.Please help in this matter.

Comment: The article I pointed already has a complete example. It even has a zip file with the source code at the end of the page (look for Resources).